# MySQL: with CREATE_USER_PRIV, GETTING "Access denied" when attempting to change another user's password

Tags: mysql, permissions, password

In MySQL 5.6.27, user `'bmcrae'` has `create user` privileges and is able to create a new user.  However, when trying to change another user's password:

```
 SQL: SET PASSWORD FOR 'newuser' = PASSWORD('***************');
```

I am getting an `"access denied"` error:

> Access denied for user 'bmcrae'@'%' to database 'mysql'

I have re-read the relevant MySQL documentation and not found anyone else having such issues.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-password.html), in order to change a password of a user, `bmcrae` must have `UPDATE` privilege for the `mysql` database.

To check the privileges of the user bmcrae, run the following command:

```
show grants for 'bmcrae'@'hostname';

OR

Show grants for bmcrae;
```

And check whether, the user `bmcrae` has `UPDATE` privilege on `mysql` database.

If the `bmcrae` doesn't have that privileges, grant update privilege to bmcrae user.

Login as a **root** user and run the following statement to grant update statement to `bmcrae` user.

```
grant update on mysql.* to 'bmcrae'@'hostname';
```

**Warning:** If you grant update privileges on mysql database, the bmcrae user can update all tables of mysql database.

Comment: Indeed; after looking further I found that requirement as well.  (I wish it were more clear in the CREATE_USER privilege documentation.)

I was concerned about giving such broad privileges, and even tried limiting to the Password column, but that is insufficient:
GRANT UPDATE (Password) ON mysql.user TO 'bmcrae';

What was also insufficient was to limit to the user table:
GRANT UPDATE ON mysql.user TO 'bmcrae';

So, I guess I will need to allow UPDATE privileges to the mysql database.

Thanks for the speedy & accurate reply.